# delegate in uiapplication sharedApplication : convention?

Tags: objective-c, delegates

in these 3 lines of code, there is this "delegate", i cannot find it anywhere else in the code, even not in the FruitsAppDelegate. I can't remember what it stands for : is it a convention? does it automatically stands for AppDelegate?

```
// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    FruitAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FruitAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return appDelegate.fruits.count;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728) defines a delegate that must adopt the [UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIApplicationDelegate) protocol and implement some of the protocol methods. Every application must have a delegate.
In your case it is FruitAppDelegate.

Comment: thanks, but specifically : `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` the "delegate" word is automatically recognized by the app as being a delegate right?

Comment: Yes. Delegation is set up automatically when you create a project. So the "delegate" property just points to your FruitAppDeleagte.